# ! Package siunitx Error: Support package expl3 too old

Tags: errors, siunitx, updating, miktex-update

I am using Texmaker and I want to use the siunitx package in my script but the computer is giving me this error message when I get it to compile my script. Does anyone know what I should do about this? Thanks.

Comment: You need to update your LaTeX installation. This is simple to do with tools accompanied with your LaTeX distribution, For example, if you use MiKTeX, open "MiKTeX console" and click on button "Check for Updates". Further steps are intuitive, just follow instruction in console.

Comment: @Zarko I'm already using the latest version of Texmaker (5.0.4) and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Texmaker is an editor, it has nothing to to with latex itself, it just calls it. As Zarko says update your latex installation. You're most likely to have miktex, and given this issue you probably have to update miktex in miktex user mode **and** in miktex admin mode.

Comment: @daleif Would you care to explain how I would do that?

Comment: Find your miktex console, it has two modes, update both. Sorry, I cannot give more details as I don't use miktex. Otherwise look at the miktex website

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864. If you are using MikTeX, also check out https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/35864.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I received this error recently and just wanted to put the suggestions in the comments because they fixed my problem:

> You need to update your LaTeX installation. This is simple to do with tools accompanied with your LaTeX distribution, For example, if you use MiKTeX, open "MiKTeX console" and click on button "Check for Updates". Further steps are intuitive, just follow instruction in console.